# Downloading a document in PWA app ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, progressive-web-apps

Just curious about this and wanted to know about this matter.

I have downloaded a PWA app and set it to my ASP.NET MVC project.

In there I want to allow download a file and for that I have used this,

```
 <a download href="@Url.Action("DownloadDoc","Ajax" ,new { id = item.Id})" target="_blank" class="btn-20 btn border-green-dark color-green-dark bi bi-arrow-down" />
```

The issue is it's not downloading, A new view will appear and the address bar shows the controller and the action, and the file Id, If I inspect this, in the **network** area I can see the file.

Normally when I used the same in HTML view, it opens up a new tab and then closes with downloading the file.

Here it won't work.

I want to know is there is another way of doing this ??

This is my controller code

```
public ActionResult DownloadDoc(int id) {
  var q = from temp in db.CustomerScannedDocuments where temp.Id == id select temp.Attachment;
  var type = from t in db.CustomerScannedDocuments where t.Id == id select t.File_Name;
  string fileType = type.First().ToString();
  string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileType);
  byte[] cover = q.First();
  if (cover != null) {
    if (ext == ".pdf") {
      return File(cover, "application/pdf");
    } else {
      return File(cover, "image/jpg");
    }

  } else {
    return null;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know is there is another way of doing this ?

There are couple of ways you could achieve your requirement. You could try in following ways:

**Way: 1**

**Controller:**

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadImage(string imageName)
        {
            var path = Path.GetFullPath("./wwwroot/ImageName/Cover/" + imageName);
            MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
            }
            memory.Position = 0;
            return File(memory, "image/png", Path.GetFileName(path));
        }
```

**Download Link HTML:**

```
<a asp-controller="Application"  asp-action="DownloadImage" class="btn btn-info" asp-route-imageName="@item.ImageName">Download</a>
```

Output:

[image]

Note: It doesn't require any `Nuget package`

***Way: 2 When you want to display PDF on your browser from database Model***

**Solution:**

```
 public ActionResult DisplayPdfOnBrowserFromDatabaseList()
        {
            
            var data = _context.Members.ToList();
            var pdf = data.ToPdf();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pdf);
            return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");

        }
```

**Note:** To handle this scenario you need to use [`3rd party Nuget package`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ArrayToPdf) which is [`ArrayToPdf`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ArrayToPdf) You can search on `Nuget package` on your visual studio. You can also check the [GitHub Link](https://github.com/mustaddon/ArrayToPdf). Finally need to add `using ArrayToPdf;` on top.

**Output:**

[image]

***Way: 3 When you want to download PDF on your browser from database model or existing file***

**Solution:**

```
public ActionResult DownloadPDFOnBrowser()
    {

        var data = _context.Members.ToList();
        var byteArray = data.ToPdf();

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

        string mimeType = "application/pdf";
        return new FileStreamResult(stream, mimeType)
        {
            FileDownloadName = "DatabaseListToPdf.pdf"
        };


    }
```

**Note:** As described above we need to add `using ArrayToPdf;` on top. To handle this scenario you need to use [`3rd party Nuget package`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ArrayToPdf) which is [`ArrayToPdf`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ArrayToPdf) You can search on `Nuget package` on your visual studio. See the screenshot below:

[image]